# What is the difference between create a folder or an object?

Tags: opc-ua, milo

how are you? I'm a new with OPC UA and I'm trying to create my first Server using the milo SDK. Just looking the ExampleNamespace we can see there are 2 types of objects to hold simple variables. Both looks the same to me, I'm talking about UaObjectTypeNode and UaFolderNode. I think there is not documentation for this SDK, if I'm wrong please show me a link or something to check it, it'll be apreciated.

Well, my questions are these:

1. What are the differences between both objects?
2. Could you give me an escenario where one can fit better than the other?

If you need additional information I will update my question, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

ObjectTypeNode is not meant to hold simple variables the way a FolderNode is.

An ObjectTypeNode is like a template, and then there will be instances of these templates (ObjectNodes) that have all the members defined on the template.

A UaFolderNode is just what it sounds like - a simple ObjectNode instance (that has a type definition of FolderTypeNode), that you can add arbitrary Organizes references to, pointing at other ObjectNodes or VariableNodes.

You really should read some of the OPC UA specs, Part 1 and Part 3 at a minimum, so you have a basic understanding of how OPC UA works.